# Iterate though Silverlight Dictionary from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I'm trying to access a Silverlight dictionary from JavaScript. As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645074%28VS.95%29.aspx#dictionary), Silverlight creates a wrapper for Dictionary types that can be accessed though JavaScript.

```
function MyFunction(dictionary)
{
    // This works okay...
    alert(dictionary["someKey"]);
}
```

However, in my case I do not know which keys are actually in the dictionary. The MSDN page does not seem to describe any way to access this information however. I've tried:

```
function MyFunction(dictionary)
{
    for (var item in dictionary)
    {
        // Do stuff
        alert(item);
    }
}
```

That doesn't work however. I've also tried using the properties and methods defined for arrays, like `length` and `toArray()`. I've tried guessing a `keys` property. Needless to say none of them work.

Is this a major oversight in the wrapper exposed by Silverlight, or am I missing something? What's the best alternative?

For completeness' sake, the Silverlight code is not very interesting, but looks something like:

```
void MyMethod(IDictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    jsObjectDefiningMyFunction.MyFunction(dictionary);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `IDictionary` wrapper *seems* like a regular JavaScript object (where you can access the properties like `object["key"]` and `object.key`, but from the documentation it looks like the only thing it supports is the getter/setter using known keys (and not iteration).

I would suggest adding another parameter to your JavaScript function that's just an array or list of the dictionary's keys, which you can then iterate on the JavaScript side, i.e.

```
string[] keys = new string[dictionary.Keys.Count];
dictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys,0);
jsObjectDefiningMyFunction.MyFunction(dictionary, keys);
```

The keys will be marshalled with an array wrapper, which can be iterated on the javascript side using the length and e.g. `myVar[3]`.

Comment: Just pass the keys as dictionary.Keys.ToArray()

Comment: Silverlight doesn't seem to support ToArray() method on KeyCollection.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't missing anything.  The `for..in` feature of Javascript is not something that COM objects support (which will be what the wrapper is fundementally).  I can imagine that would be a fairly tricky thing to achieve from Silverlight.

The alternatives really depend on what your Javascript code really needs to do.  Here is one approach which create a standard javascript object where `for..in` will work:-

```
        ScriptObject o = HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("Object");
        foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
        {
            o.SetProperty(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        } 

        jsObjectDefiningMyFunction.MyFunction(o);
```

However I suspect in most scenario this is a very inefficient approach, but really does depend on the javascript usage scenario.  For example this is perfect for constructing objects to be passed in to many JQuery methods.   On the other hand is terrible for occasionally looking up the current value of a single item and useless if you then need to update that value.